# Is the beach in Iquique, Chile near to the city centre and tourist accommodation?

Tags: beaches, chile

Is the beach in Iquique, Chile near to the city centre and tourist accommodation?

Can I easily walk around the city and to the beach or do I need public transport?

Comment: *For how long should I stay in Iquique ?* -- That would be up to you and depend on all that you want to do.  But as far as Q&A is concerned it's going to be impossible to answer

Comment: @Karlson I've updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really not far from downtown.  I and a friend [were there in 2010](http://www.marksmayo.com/2011/04/06/iquique-warm-in-the-north-of-chile/) for just a day (that link is my blog), and we walked all over town, including down to the beach. There's not that much in the way of sights, but it's a nice enough stop off for a day or two.  Definitely walkable from bus station to central sites to the beach and back (my friend isn't a big walker and he was fine with it too).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Is the beach nice ? I actually plan to go there because it is a good bus connection, and I would like to spend 1 or 2 days on the beach indeed.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't bad, would be great on a warm summer day :)

Answer (score 0):

The main beach in Iquique is Cavancha. [You can walk there](http://maps.google.cl/maps?saddr=Baquedano,+Iquique,+Tarapac%C3%A1&daddr=Arturo+Prat+Chac%C3%B3n&hl=es-419&ie=UTF8&ll=-20.223342,-70.146332&spn=0.031048,0.066047&sll=-20.230671,-70.145431&sspn=0.031046,0.066047&geocode=FbF-y_4dgJDR-ynJMIXT_RNSkTH6pZMnDTYfHA%3BFVRKy_4dH6jR-w&dirflg=w&mra=ltm&t=m&z=15) (on the itinerary, A: City center; B: The best Iquique's beach)